# How HTTP method works in a form_tag helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

I tried to set up a form which I wanted it to move to members#index.
But with the code①, I failed and the form moved to members#show.

☆code①

```
<%= form_tag :action => 'index' do %>
 <div class = "field">
  <%= label_tag 'place', '活動場所：'　%><br />
  <%= text_field_tag 'place' %>
 </div> 
 <%= submit_tag '検索' %>
<% end %>
```

And I got some advice and fixed the code②.
I have a question. Why did I have to change the method from "post" to "get"?

☆code2

```
   <div class= "form_index">
      <%= form_tag({:action=>"index"}, {:method=>"get"}) do %>
       <div class="from_field_index">
        <%= label_tag 'place', '場所:' %>
        <%= text_field_tag 'place' %>
       </div>
       <div class="search_button">
       <%= submit_tag '検索' %>
      <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

☆members_controller

```
  def index
      if params[:place].present?
       @members = Member.where("place like ?" , "%" + params[:place] + "%")
      else
       @members = Member.all 
      end

       respond_to do |format|
       format.html # index.html.erb
       format.json
      end 
   end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GET` implies to retrieve something from server. `POST` implies to add something to server.

Search will get some results from server, so the conventional way is to use `GET` on this action. Search form is the perfect example of form using GET.

Also, your controller action `index` responds to 'GET' only, defined by default resource route. It also need the request sent by your client side to be 'GET'.

Another benefit of using GET on search is, the params will be in url so the url is bookmarkable, shareable and history nagivatable. Think about Google, you can share a search result by just copying the link.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. Billy Chan. Now I understand.